# Is the truncated to 64 bit sha1 of a 64 bit number guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: openssl, sha1

I'm not a crypto expert, or even trying to do cryptography, but I need to decorrelate a 64 bit hash (For the SimHash algorithm, in case anyone cares). If I take the lowest 64 bits of a SHA1 has over a 64 bit key (8 bytes), it the result guaranteed to be unique? It is most likely "Close Enough To Unique", but I'd like to know for sure.

(To answer the "What I've Tried", I've run a for loop with the upper 32 section iterating from 0 to 10000, and the lower 32 bit doing the same without hits.)

Comment: I see no reason why. The truncated to 8 bit sha1 of an 8-bit number is not unique. (The bottom 8 bits of SHA1(11) and SHA1(186) are both 6.)

Comment: Fair nuff. Its more of a pain, but I'll modified to use the full 20 byte key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Raymond Chen, the answer is no